# HexColor does not work in backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, background-color

I have this small code and I have two buttons in it and I want the color of the first button to become green when I point the mouse at it and the color of the second button to become red when I point the mouse at it

But when I put the name of the color within the “backgroundColor” I did not find any problem in the code, but when I put “hex like (#43a047)” it did not work, how can I solve the problem?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button1: {
    backgroundColor: "none",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#43a047",
      color: "#e8e4e4",
    },
  },
  button2: {
    backgroundColor: "none",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#e53935",
      color: "#e8e4e4",
    },
  },
});

 <ButtonGroup
              style={{
                // color: "#f8f4fc",
                // backgroundColor: "#282c3c",
                maxWidth: "206px",
                maxHeight: "40px",
                minWidth: "206px",
                minHeight: "40px",
                // marginRight: 10,
              }}
              aria-label="outlined primary button group"
            >
              <Button
                style={{
                  maxWidth: "100px",
                  minWidth: "100px",
                }}
                className={classes.button}
              >
                approve
              </Button>
              <Button
                style={{
                  maxWidth: "100px",
                  minWidth: "100px",
                }}
              >
                reject
              </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
```

Comment: Can you try using `background` instead of `backgroundColor` if that helps? They use it like that [here](https://mui.com/styles/basics/)

Comment: the problem still there

Comment: Oh, in `useStyles` you have `button1` and `button2` but in `<Button>` you have `{classes.button}`. Add the number there or change the whole name of the class.

Comment: Oh my gosh, forgot to change it, thanks, it's fixed

Comment: I will make it into an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `className={classes.button}` you have to use same name as you have in `makeStyles`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have spelled the CSS property wrong. You put backgroundColor: "#43a047"; and it is supposed to be background-color: #43a047;

Comment: It is a `JavaScript object`.

Comment: this is material ui+ css, and the rules for material ui that i must to write backgroundColor not background-color

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how this will be transformed to CSS, but in CSS rules that parameter's name is "background-color", not the JS equivalent "backgroundColor"

Comment: i edit my tags @Johannes